# Naming facts exported from blocks in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I'm using Isabelle/HOL.  Isabelle exports the last fact in a block, allowing the context that contains the block to use it.  Ordinarily when I generate facts, I can give them convenient names.  How do I name facts that are exported from blocks?

Simple example:

```
lemma mylemma: "i=i"
proof -
  {
      fix j::nat
      have "j=j" by auto
    }

    show ?thesis using ‹⋀j. j = j› by auto
  qed
```

Right now I use `‹⋀j. j = j›` to refer to the exported fact as a proposition literal.  I'd like to be able give it a simple name, though, as when I named the lemma `mylemma`.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From section 1.1.2 in the document isar-ref: you can reference facts via explicit name, implicit name and literal position. In this case, the explicit name has not been provided. I believe that the canonical method to provide an explicit name is to reference the fact of interest by its implicit name immediately after the end of the block. For example,

```
lemma mylemma: "i = i"
proof -
  {
    fix j :: nat
    have "j = j" by auto
  }
  note name = this
  show ?thesis using name by auto
qed
```

---

As a side remark, I would like to mention that general questions about Isabelle or the syntax of Isar are best posed on Stack Overflow. I believe that this would drastically increase the chances of your questions being answered promptly.